# Java - grouping identical exceptions in logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is there any logging solution with exception grouping feature? What I want to achieve is when some exception is logged for example 100 times in 10 seconds I don't want to log 100 stack traces. I want to log something like `RuntimeException was thrown 100 times: single stack trace here`. It'd perfect to have something integrated with `log4j`.

Ofc there is an option to create some logging facade with exception queue inside but maybe there is something already implemented.

Comment: Just a thought: how would you handle logs interlacing induced by the different threads? e.g. if one thread logs X a great number of times and another thread logs Y a great number of times, you may end up with X Y X Y X Y X Y. I had to do something similar on a previous project and the third-party logging framework was not the solution (we implemented our own grouping mechanism....)

Comment: @xav yes, ofc there will be some concurrency problems. Solution in my case could be synchronized logging methods / concurrency collections for storing state with sequenced exception or smth similar. So X Y X Y X Y -> Xx3 Yx3. Could you please tell a little more about how your grouping mechanism was implemented?

Comment: I didn't talk about this kind of concurrency. Having two threads logging at the *same time* will be fine for log4j. Using `synchronized` in your code won't help at all for the issue I talked about. I talked about this kind of case: a thread TX logs X, then two seconds later, another thread TY logs Y, then two seconds later, thread TX logs X, then two seconds later, thread TY logs Y, .... As a result, your log file will contain X Y X Y X Y... (except if you have one log file per thread, which would be weird)

Comment: @xav in my case this is not actually a problem but I think it wouldn't be hard to implement some storage for all of exceptions and for each new one define whether it's a single exception or a sequenced.

Comment: How about using logstash which reads that reads your logs, you can write filters in logstash for grouping and then write back the new logs to another file.

Comment: Someone created yesterday a feature request to implement this in log4j2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1464  (via similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395844)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this [log handler implementation that groups logs](https://github.com/andresoviedo/java-utilities/blob/master/src/main/java/org/andresoviedo/util/log/jul/MailHandler.java) for then sending to an email address.

The solution is basically a [log handler](https://github.com/andresoviedo/java-utilities/blob/master/src/main/java/org/andresoviedo/util/log/jul/MailHandler.java) that uses a [CyclicBuffer](https://github.com/andresoviedo/java-utilities/blob/master/src/main/java/org/andresoviedo/util/data/CyclicBuffer.java) to save logs to memory. When a threshold is reached or the system is closes, the handler flushes the buffer.

The solution is **JUL based** (java.util.logging), but it may serve you as basis for you to build your own log4j solution with a few modifications. It worked nice for me. Hope it helps.