# Counting repeating lines instead of displaying all of them in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have seen a log once that looked like this. Not sure what logging framework generated it.

```
12:34:56 INFO blah
... previous line repeated 23 times
11:22:33 DEBUG blah
```

Can this be done with log4j2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version, Log4j 2.6.2, does not have this capability. I'm not sure how easy it would be to implement this, but I would definitely recommend that you raise a feature request for this on the [Log4j 2 issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2).

A similar request may already exist to suppress repeated stack traces, but I think your idea is different enough to warrant a separate Jira ticket.

Comment: For the record, here is the link to this (useful!) feature request: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1464

Comment: Nice! Thanks for raising this.